# Python and mySQL, INSERT works but SELECT returns -1...!

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I think I'm going mad, so please, your help will be appreciated...

I'm experimenting with RDS from AWS and I've setup a simple MySQL database.

One table: MyTable: id (int, auto increment), col1 (varchar(64)), col2 (int).

I try the following code, but fail to get things working properly:

```
myString = base64.standard_b64encode("myTestString")
myInt = 0

config = {
'user': db_username,
'password': db_password,
'host': db_host,
'database': db_database,
'raise_on_warnings': True,
'charset' :'utf8',
}

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)

cursor1 = cnx.cursor()
SQLa = ("INSERT INTO myTable (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)")
SQLav = (myString, myInt)
cursor1.execute(SQLa, SQLav)
cnx.commit()            

cursor2 = cnx.cursor()
SQLq = ("SELECT id, col1, col2 FROM myTable WHERE col1 = '%s'")
SQLv = (myString)
cursor2.execute(SQLq, SQLv)

print cursor2.rowcount

rows = cursor2.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)

cursor1.close()
cursor2.close()
cnx.close()
```

The INSERT works, within the MySQL Workbench I see the row added.

The SELECT though always returns -1!

I've tried without the '' in the SELECT, but I get an error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

How can I make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: I would not expect the `insert` to work because the string values are not delimited.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - the code does INSERT a row in the database with no errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query takes %s and wraps it in '', which means the mysql connector sees this as a string literal, not as a placeholder to be replaced by your values.
Remove the '' around %s and it should work fine.

```
SQLq = ("SELECT id, col1, col2 FROM myTable WHERE col1 = '%s'")
```

becomes

```
SQLq = ("SELECT id, col1, col2 FROM myTable WHERE col1 = %s")
```

Also, the SQLv = (mystring) does not become a tuple, it is still a string
To make SQLv a tuple, you have to add a comma (not very intuitive)

```
SQLv = (mystring, )
```

Comment: This way I get the error I mentioned: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

Comment: @Kostas Yeah, sorry, I was a bit fast at posting. Forgot half the solution. Added the whole solution now.

Comment: Works perfectly! One comma... made the differnce! Thank you @firelynx!